# Scss. Миксин font-face

Tags: sass, scss, шрифты

```
@mixin font-face($font-family, $file-path, $weight: normal, $style: normal, $asset-pipeline: false ) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: $font-family;
        font-weight: $weight;
        font-style: $style;

        @if $asset-pipeline == true {
            src: font-url('#{$file-path}.eot');
            src: font-url('#{$file-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            font-url('#{$file-path}.woff2') format('woff2'),
            font-url('#{$file-path}.woff') format('woff'),
            font-url('#{$file-path}.ttf') format('truetype'),
            font-url('#{$file-path}.svg##{$font-family}') format('svg');
        } @else {
                src: url('#{$file-path}.eot');
                src: url('#{$file-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('#{$file-path}.woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('#{$file-path}.woff') format('woff'),
                url('#{$file-path}.ttf') format('truetype'),
                url('#{$file-path}.svg##{$font-family}') format('svg');
        }
    }
}
```

Использую такой миксин для шрифтов, но не понимаю зачем нужна строчка `$asset-pipeline: false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это для поддержки Rails

[To make this work with asset pipeline in Rails 4.2 I changed url to font-url.](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d0460e5c2d5d7f9bc5e6#gistcomment-2117887)